# python: creating an irregular iterator

Tags: python, arrays, sequence

This is a stumper. How can I create the following sequence:

```
x = 3,4,9,10, ..., 6k+3, 6k+4
```

so I can use it elsewhere:

```
y = [something(i) for i in x]
```

Any ideas? I can't seem to think of one.

Comment: Where is the question ?

Comment: reworded to make it clearer

Comment: Maybe I need more coffee or something. What exactly is the pattern in the sequence?

Comment: @JasonS the equation is not correct eg. when k = 1

Comment: @jamylak - That was my incorrect edit; I removed it rather than fixing, since I noticed it's basically your answer :)

Comment: @chepner I figured you were just copying what @JasonS wrote so it wasn't your fault directly. You could fix it by using `floor` of the division, it wouldn't be exactly the same as my answer since mine just uses integer division which isn't a mathematical notation

Comment: what do you mean by `for i in x`, this sequence goes forever so how many values do you want?

Comment: the sequence is finite. (and yes, I'm not rigorous about it, the example I gave is wrong for k=0 or 1)

Answer (score 6):

The answer by [@JasonS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697375/1219006) is most readable but this is a nice one-liner

```py
def F(N):
    return (6*(i//2) + 3+(i%2) for i in xrange(N))

>>> list(F(10))
[3, 4, 9, 10, 15, 16, 21, 22, 27, 28]
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, unfortunately, because the question requires the result of this function for arbitrary values from a list or other sequence, not just a slice of the sequence.

Comment: @kindall I agree it's not a full answer but I thought when OP said `for i in x`, `x` referred to this endless sequence. OP may edit this function to suit their needs but I will ask for clarification

Answer (score 4):

hmm, I ended up just doing this

```
def indicesGenerator(N):
    for i in xrange(0, N, 6):
        yield i+3
        yield i+4
```

Comment: ...and I suppose it should be `xrange` for large N, not `range`

Comment: +1 This is a lot clearer than both other ways, you should accept your own answer ;)

Comment: I have now changed my answer to use `xrange` as well, I still think this is most readable however

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your function needs to return two values, which means you'll get a list of tuples, not the flat list of values you want. `itertools.chain` to the rescue!

```
from itertools import chain

def something(x):
    return 6 * x + 3, 6 * x + 4

x = [3, 5, 7]
y = list(chain.from_iterable(something(i) for i in x))
```

Comment: Good call, that simplifies it.